# No overload matches this call | Typescript + React + Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I'm getting started with TypeScript for React combined with Material UI and I'm getting stuck with my very first component.

```js
// material
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function Logo() {
  return (
    <Box
      component="img"
      alt="logo"
      src="/static/brand/logo.svg"
      height={40}
    />
  );
}
```

I am getting errors at alt and src: No overload matches this call.
I have the feeling that this is related to some configuration of the repo, but I still don't know what.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It throws the no overload matches this call because the Box component doesn't have the props you are trying to pass. `alt` and `src`

A better approach would be to use the `<Box />` as a wrapper if you want to set the size of the image

```
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Logo() {
  return (
    <Box height={40}>
      <img
        alt="logo"
        src="/static/brand/logo.svg"
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

> The Box component serves as a wrapper component for most of the CSS
> utility needs.

https://material-ui.com/components/box/

The `component` prop changes the component that it renders in the DOM (`<div>` is by default), but it shouldn't be used as the component itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using the code from a component of a template I purchased. Do you know if that is a eslint config problem or a tsconfig one?

Comment: Glad that helped! This is ts one I believe, but I wouldn't say it's a problem, it is quite handy and helps you to pass props that are only available for a component. It is only a compiler error and it wouldn't cause problems when the app is built.

Comment: I just discovered that with the next update from material-ui (https://next.material-ui.com/) that would work haha